# Is there commandline equivalent of "Copy as insert" of DataStax DevCenter?

Tags: cassandra

I've used DataStax DevCenter and noticed the `Copy as insert` feature to be very useful; this feature allows the user to copy the result of `select` statement into the clipboard in the format of `INSERT` CQL statement.

Is there any means to achieve such via commandline?

Answer (score 1):

If by command line you mean using cqlsh, then no it isn't able to generate Insert statements.

You might be interested in a new feature of DevCenter 1.6.0 which can export all results directly to a file, either as CSV or INSERT statements.